# How to select only part of a JSON string

Tags: postgresql

I have a field that returns

```
{"nextPONumber":"3","poReportFooter":"This is the footer text for a purchase order report"}
```

I want to pull just the

> "This is the footer text for a purchase order report"

```
SELECT
  modulesetting.value AS footer_value
FROM modulesetting
WHERE modulesetting.key='purchasing'
```

Comment: Use the [built-in JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: what is the name of the field?..

Comment: the field is footer_value which returns {"nextPONumber":"3","poReportFooter":"This is the footer text for a purchase order report"}

Comment: then qry in my answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in JSON functionality:

```
select
    modulesetting.value::json->>'poReportFooter'
from
    modulesetting
WHERE modulesetting.key='purchasing';
```

[More info on the built-in JSON functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

a wild guess:

```
SELECT
  modulesetting.value->>'poReportFooter' AS footer_value
FROM modulesetting
WHERE modulesetting.key='purchasing'
```